# How to convert TIS-620 string to UTF-8 string in Java?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

How do I convert TIS-620 (the extended ASCII Thai Character code page) string to UTF-8 string in Java?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.CharBuffer
```

....

```
public static ByteBuffer toByteBuffer(String content, String encode) {  
      Charset charset = Charset.forName(encode);  
      ByteBuffer bb = charset.encode(content);  
       return bb;  
   }
```

Pass as encode argument "UTF-8"

Comment: still not working out quite right !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
private byte[] convertTis620ToUTF8(byte[] encoded)
{
    try
    {
        String theString = new String(encoded, "TIS620");
        return theString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } 
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
    {
        /* Didn't work out */
    }
}

...

byte[] utf8 = convertTis620ToUTF8(tis620);
```

Also, you might need to put charsets.jar on your classpath to support the TIS620 encoding.