# Convert String with encoding UTF-8 to TIS620 (Thai encoding) in Java.What are the ways to do it and it there any data loss?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

As an input the string will be any Thai char string with UTF-8 encoding,
Covert this string format from **UTF-8** to **TIS620** in Java.

1. Can that be achieved by java.io.Charset?
2. Is there any data loss or increase in char size post encoding?
3. Any java utility/open source available for any encoding conversion?

I'm new to character encoding and checked few online help links but could not find any with reference to TIS620

Input is input string to be converted e.g.

> ๕ค 9 ๖ต 0 ๗จ - ๘ข = ๙ช q ๐ๆ w \"ไ e ฎำ r ฑพ t ธะ y ํั u ๊ี i ณร o ฯน p ญย [ ฐบ ] ,ล ⏎ ⇥ a ฤฟ s ฆห d ฏก f โด g ฌเ h ็้ j ๋่ k ษา l ศส ; ซ

encoding - tis 620

```
public static String encode(String input, String encoding) {
    //   byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
    return new String(input.getBytes(), Charset.forName(encoding));
}
```

Expected output is the given UTF-8 string will be converted to TIS 620 encoding

Comment: The problem starts with the `encode` method having a `String` as input and result. Strings in Java are a sequence of characters, independent of encoding. Instead, use byte arrays to represent encoded strings. Then decode the UTF-8 to a string and encode that string in TIS620.

Comment: Thanks @henry , so public static String encode(byte[] input, String encoding) will be sufficient right?

Comment: No, `public static byte[] encode(byte[] input, String encoding)`

Comment: No, actually it should be `public static byte[] encode(String input, Charset encoding)`: you want to encode a String into a byte array using a given Charset. If you take a byte[] as argument, you'll first have to decode it to a String (using which charset?), and then re-encode it.

Comment: I've use case where I get multiple String values from JSON file and I need to convert  encoding of few of those strings to TIS620 but  even the converted strings will be added to String buffer,  for example, I get Str1,str2,str3 from json file.I read all values then only str2 encoding if I change to TIS620 but at the end I add all to StringBuilder which ultimately uses toString() and this is UTF-16. Will my encoding for converted string will again gets converted to UTF16?

Comment: @Henry No, at the API level, a `String` is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. While you could consider `String` to "not have an encoding" for most text processing, any use of length, offset, or decomposition into `char` or `Character` has to take UTF-16 into account. (As well use of \uHHHH notation inside character or string literals.)

Comment: @TomBlodget I know, of course there is an internal representation. But for the most part one can ignore that. It becomes only visible if you handle characters outside of the BMP.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is nothing special about TIS-620. Although not every Java implementation is required to support it, main full-sized implementations do.

Yes, there can be data loss: Unicode is much bigger than TIS-620. In particular, two characters in your string are not supported: ⏎ ⇥
Typically, unsupported characters are replaced by ? but other behaviors such as an exception are possible.

```
Charset.forName("TIS620")
    .encode("๕ค 9 ๖ต 0 ๗จ - ๘ข = ๙ช q ๐ๆ w \"ไ e ฎำ r ฑพ t ธะ y ํั u ๊ี i ณร o ฯน p ญย [ ฐบ ] ,ล ⏎ ⇥ a ฤฟ s ฆห d ฏก f โด g ฌเ h ็้ j ๋่ k ษา l ศส ; ซ")
    .array()
```

Comment: Hi Tom and @Henry - so if I use above it'll encode my string to TIS620 and post that if i add this string to another string will encoding will change to UTF or remain as it is ? e.g.     
 String thai =Charset.forName("TIS620").encode("ข้อมูลการโอนเงิน").toString();
        StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
        test.append("check");
        test.append(thai);
        test.toString();

Comment: Is this correct way of encoding conversion ?                                           
        String input= "ข้อมูลการโอนเงิน";
        byte[] tis6201 = Charset.forName("TIS620").encode(input).array();
        String converted = new String(tis6201, "TIS620");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(converted);
        sb.append("---------check this value");

Comment: No, the result of encoding is a byte array, not a String. You could concatenate the strings and then encode to TIS-620. What are you doing with the TIS-620 output?

Comment: But that is not my requirement, out of say 10 String I need to encode only 2 string to TIS 620 , add all strings to StringBuilder and then return complete as string for further processing so I cannot encode whole string. In summary only few field values which I get as Thai character I need to convert it to TIS620 ans then process further.

Comment: I don't think you are doing a straightforward character encoding operation. Please edit your question with an example. Keep in mind that all Strings are UTF-16, so if you say they involve TIS-620 somehow, there must be some kind of layering that needs to be described.

Comment: @TomBlodget- I get Thai char string with UTF8 encoding as input, now I need to store this string with tis620 encoding so that thai characters are stored correctly in the back end storage i.e. Mainframe system which accepts only 2bytes of data.You are right I need to convert all the strings encoding to tis620.I found one post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246489/how-to-convert-tis-620-string-to-utf-8-string-in-java/782201#782201 I think this will solve my problem by just doing the reverse.

Comment: Please check below if this is correct? I see UTF8 byte length is 3 times more than that of TIS620

Comment: That would be approximately correct.  UTF-8 encode different codepoints in 1, 2 , 3 or 4 8-bit code units.

Comment: I've created new thread here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181867/java-how-to-verify-if-thai-characters-are-encoded-correctly-from-utf-8-to-tis62